# How to remove(pop) element from a stack implementation?

Tags: java, oop, implementation

Currently working on my home assignment, a simulation code to make stack with a support of dynamic array.
The method `pop()` is not working to it is function, I wrote some of the code but I need a completion. My stack should be simulates like this, you insert a numbers to be called top then remove that number(top).

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MyStack implements IntStack {

    int[] heltal;

    public MyStack() {
        heltal = new int[0];
    }

    public void push(int tal) {

        int[] temp = new int[heltal.length + 1];

        for (int x = 0; x < heltal.length; x++) {
            temp[x] = heltal[x] + tal;

        }
        heltal = temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < heltal.length; i++) {
            heltal[i] = tal;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int pop() {
        if (Isempty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The stack is empty, there is nothing to pop");

        } else {

            int[] temp = new int[heltal.length - 1];

            for (int x = 0; x < heltal.length - 1; x++) {
                temp[x] = heltal[x];

            }

            int etttal = heltal[0];


            heltal = temp;
            return etttal;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int peek() {
        if (Isempty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The stack is empty");
        } else {
            return heltal[0];
        }

    }

    public boolean Isempty() {
        return heltal.length == 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: your `push` method is wrong. What is the purpose of the line `temp[x] = heltal[x] + tal;`?

Comment: The second loop makes no sense either.

Comment: That `push()` function is very very wrong. Also the creator - why allocate a 0 length array - just leave it null until you have data to put in there. Which end of the array are you intending to pop from ? You cut off the last one and treturn the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be making this more difficult than required.  For a stack implementation, `push`, `pop`, `peek`, and others are nothing more than index manipulators that return or store a value.  The stack can be backed by an array or a list. And `pushing` et al are abstract terms. So when you push a value, you  do not need to copy everything down by one.  Just add it to the end of your data structure.

- pop - check the index and if valid, return the element at the current index, update the index.
- push - store the value at the next location. Probably index + 1 but it depends on how you implement it.
- peek - return the top value (at the index) but don't update the index.

If you are using an array, you need to add method(s) to increase it's capacity.

For more information, check out [Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))

Here is a simple push method, backed by an `array` called `stack` and an `index` field. It presumes `ints` are being used.

```
public void push(int v) {
    if (index == stack.length-1) {
    // no more room, increase array size
    // while retaining current values.
    }
    stack[++index] = v;
}
```